# Editing posts shouldn't require a manual refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app

After submitting an edit to a post **directly from the edit preview screen** and returning to the main Q&A view, the edit isn't visible and you're instead greeted with a banner asking you to manually reload. This is unnecessary and the view should reload automatically.

> [image]

> [image]

---

- App Version: 1.6.2.1
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this.  When I edit a question or answer, the post is updated and the "Question edited" banner isn't there.  I've tried the following cases: Question edit, answer edit, question edit with banner initially on screen, question edit having navigated to another screen before submitting.

Comment: @Brian maybe with a slow/bumpy connection?

Comment: Well that is strange, it was consistently happening now I can't repro either. I'll do some more test shortly and see if I can figure out what was going on

Comment: @BrianNickel Got it... only happens from the preview view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.2.5.

When you press Submit, the processing gets handled by the offscreen question editor view controller.  Because the editor is offscreen, there are a variety of actions that will fail if attempted.  For example, if submitting has an error that requires an alert, that alert needs to come from the onscreen navigation controller.

In this case, I was sending the instruction to show the edit up the responder chain, but since the sender wasn't in the view hierarchy, it silently failed.  Passing `self.navigationController` as the sender fixed it.